# Dialogflow Phone Gateway User Response Capture Time

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am building a Voice bot in dialogflow using Phone Gateway.Is there any timeout limit for User Response ?.
In the dialogflow intent training i gave @any i.e @sys.any ,so user can say anything.
But the issue which i see is if the user need to give his response say for 1 minute or more,dialogflow intent is not waiting it is jumping to next intent after few seconds.How to make dialogflow phone gateway to wait for longer time for the user response ?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this as well.